# Question about proof of closure of set.

Tags: general-topology

Let $\Gamma$ be the Moore Plane Topology and consider the following set:
\begin{equation*}
    A=\bigcup_{q\in\mathbb{Q}\setminus \{ 0\}} \left(\{q\} \times \left[0,\frac{1}{d_q}\right]\right).
\end{equation*}

Where $q = \frac{n_q}{d_q}: n_q,d_q \in \mathbb{Z}$ are relativily prime and $d_q >0$.

I am tring to show that if $x \in \{0\} \cup (\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q})$ and $y = 0$, then $(x,0) \in \operatorname{cl}(A)$.

Below is my attempt:

(my) **Solution:** let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and consider the tangent disk at $(x,0)$ of radius $\epsilon > 0$. Let $q \in \mathbb{Q}(q = \frac{n_q}{d_q})$ such that $|x-q|<\sqrt{(\frac{1}{d_q})(2\epsilon - \frac{1}{d_q})}$. Then the point $(q, \frac{1}{d_q}) \in A$ is in the tangent disk at $(x,0)$ of radius $\epsilon > 0$, since, the following holds:
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        (x-q)^2 + (\epsilon - \frac{1}{d_q})^2 &< (\frac{1}{d_q})(2\epsilon - \frac{1}{d_q}) + (\epsilon - \frac{1}{d_q})^2 = \epsilon^2.
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}
Therefore, for any $\epsilon > 0$ we have $D_{(x,0),\epsilon} \cap A \neq \emptyset$, hence, the point
$(x,0) \in \operatorname{cl}_{\tau} (A)$, for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Therefore, $\mathbb{R} \times \{0\}$, i.e. the $x$-axis, is in the closure.

Comment: I think that you want $d_q$ everywhere that you’ve written $d_1$ in your solution. How do you know that there **is** a rational $q$ such that $|x-q|<\sqrt{\frac{2\epsilon}{d_q}-\frac1{d_q^2}}$? You don’t know how big the righthand side of the inequality is until you’ve chosen $q$, but you don’t know how close $q$ has to be to $x$ until after you’ve chosen $q$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott you're right, I do mean to have $d_q$ instead of $d_1$...typo! I will fix that. I see your point... I though I could say there exists such a $q$ since the rationals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. you can find one close to any $x \in \mathbb{R}$?.

Comment: It’s possible to find one that works, but one has to work a little harder than that. I’ve written up an answer giving one possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$. There is a prime $p$ such that $\frac2p<\epsilon$, so there is a rational $q\in(x,x+\epsilon)\setminus\Bbb Z$ such that $d_q=p$. Using a prime ensures that $d_q$ really is $p$ unless $q$ is an integer, and taking $p$ large enough so that $\frac2p<\epsilon$ ensures that there are at least two consecutive multiples of $\frac1p$ between $x$ and $x+\epsilon$, so that we can can choose one that isn’t an integer. Then

$$\begin{align*}
|x-q|^2+\left(\epsilon-\frac1{d_q}\right)^2&\le\frac1{p^2}+\epsilon^2-\frac{2\epsilon}p+\frac1{p^2}\\
&=\epsilon^2+\frac{2-2p\epsilon}{p^2}\\
&<\epsilon^2\,,
\end{align*}$$

since $p\epsilon>1$, and therefore $\left\langle q,\frac1{d_q}\right\rangle\in D(\langle q,0\rangle,\epsilon)$.

Comment: This was great! Thanks

Comment: @Dalton: You’re welcome!